# Changing the ending of "Suffer with Me"

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When at the ending of "Suffer with Me," how do I change the ending? I've pressed rewind story at the replay mission but I always have to kill "Menendez." I've even rewinded the entire campaign and it never works.

Answer (score 1):

Every single story line involves this ending in the level. There are a couple of decision points in the game that will affect later storylines and decisions however this is not one.

> No matter what you must kill Alex as this is what causes Menendez to shoot Hudson and spawnes the hate in David after seeing his father die.

Storyline spoiler:

> If the player wounds Mason by shooting him anywhere but the head or chest, he will survive. However he will remain absent in the thirty year gap for reasons unknown. In the ending cutscene, Mason visits Woods at The Vault. Soon David comes to visit Woods and is re-introduced to Alex, who tells him that the day that David fell from the tree was the one that made Alex proud as he got back up.